# What is the best Stack Exchange site where business related questions can be asked?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question about small-scale enterprises. What is the best site that can be asked on?

Comment: Go to stackexchange.com, click on "All Sites" and click on "Business"

Comment: Here is a list of all the released [Business Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites#business) sites. I'll let you decide which is best.

Comment: I couldn't edit the last comment, so just reposted with fixed link. Copy paste error

Comment: thanks jim and james....:)

Comment: FYI: There is also: [Accounting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82671/accounting) proposal.

Comment: Is it time to try to relaunch a business and or start up site? Seems like there would be demand for it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are some options for you, it will largely depend on what your question is actually about:

## The Workplace

> The Workplace - Stack Exchange is for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting.

http://workplace.stackexchange.com

## Ask Patents

> Ask Patents - Stack Exchange is a collaboratively edited Q&A platform for patent experts, inventors and citizens who wish to participate in the US patent process. Its primary purpose is to help individuals:
>
> Solicit help finding prior art that might apply to a patent or application
> Get answers to hard questions about specific patents
> Ask questions about the US patent system or process

http://patents.stackexchange.com

## Startups

**The Startups site didn't have enough activity during the beta and has been closed.**

> Q&A about the site for entrepreneurs faced with delivering a new product or service under conditions of significant uncertainty

https://startups.stackexchange.com

---

Without knowing the *exact* content of your question I would say that Startups is your best bet - see if there is a precedent for the question you want to ask or look on the per-site meta.

Comment: +1.  While AskPatents seems unlikely based on the limited info available, the formatting and detail here is a lot better than mine was.

Comment: Startups is dead :( Because of the hightech nature of stack exchange visitors, startups would have been a great community to have here.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com is one of the worst places to ask "business related" questions. Expect to get heavily downvoted for posting business related questions there. They only want "workplace related" questions. "Workplace" does not equal "business".

Comment: Interesting, I'm surprised there isn't a Business Administration stack exchange with information about setting up DBAs, best practices for management organization, advice on surprising rules in different countries, etc

Answer (score 1):

How small?  What kind of "business" questions?

If you mean "very small", [Startups SE](https://startups.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  may fit the bill.

If the questions is about general professional advice for work, [the workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) site might fit.

Comment: Sadly, the Startups SE is now closed.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2020, the [business Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#business-newest) are:

- [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/)
- [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/)
- [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally a business related question may be on topic on [Personal Money & Finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/)