# Accept vote isn't shown in an accepted answer's timeline

Tags: bug, accepted-answer, timeline

Checking the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65524654/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) of an accepted answer of mine, I can't see the accept vote for my answer.

[image: timeline of an accepted answer]

As per https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271754, it should be available:

> The accept vote is available on the accepted answer's timeline.

This [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272892/new-timeline-view-only-shows-last-accept-vote-no-un-accepts) also confirms that is has been available at some point.

Sadly I couldn't find a screenshot of an accepted vote in the timeline after the timeline was changed some years ago.

Comment: Even worse, when answer is *unaccepted*, the accept event just disappears from the timeline and there's no way to know it was ever accepted.

Comment: Duplicate of: "[New timeline view only shows \*last\* accept vote, no un-accepts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272892/271271)"

Comment: @Makyen Well, the timeline currently doesn't show the latest accept vote either, even for currently accepted items. So similar, but not duplicates. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73487830/timeline -- you can see a given answer _is_ accepted in the question timeline, but not when. And when you go to the answer's timeline, nothing whatsoever is shown.

Answer (score 6):

It's true that the **answer** from [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65521101/3648282) doesn't show in the timeline that it was accepted:

[image: Timeline of Answer]

Instead the *accept* is shown in the timeline of the **question**, with a tickmark next to the chosen answer:

[image: Timeline of Question]

This is useful when there are multiple answers, some before and some after the accepted answer; such as [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169515/282094):

[image: Timeline of alternate example question]

Votes (which includes accepting and unaccepting) [are always aggregated in the timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354588/282094), a higher level of detail isn't available to users; even though it's obvious that the *voter* was almost certainly the one who asked the question (moderators and staff can change the acceptance, in [rare](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279102/282094) circumstances).

A request for details: "[New timeline view only shows *last* accept vote, no un-accepts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272892/282094)" has already been filled on Jan 13 '16 at 14:43.

Comment: This doesn't really address the problem stated in my question. I'm talking about something that was shown and now isn't shown anymore. This seems to be a regression, as I didn't find any evidence that indicates it was removed on purpose.

Comment: I do not think moderators can change the accept status of an answer (source: I am a moderator), and I do not think staff ever does it (they are always [pretty clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80321/643262) that an accept should only come from the asker). The link you provide does not seem to state this. Is there something that I have missed?

Comment: Wimi, yes; and it's been done; and documented.